# Visual Basic Member Already Exists in an object module

Tags: vba

I am brand new to visual basic today and I was writing my program but I get a compile error

> Member already exists in an object module from which this object module derives

My function prototype is

```
Function calculate(count As Integer) As String
```

I was wondering why this is giving me this error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It would appear that you are designing a form, and have an object on that form (such as a text box or command button) which is also named `calculate`, disregarding case, since VBA is generally not case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your function has same name as the system's reserve function name, such as `AfterInsert()`